# lapply on a list of dataframe to create plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a list of dataframe `df_list`, each of which is an 18 x 4 dataframe.
The first columns of the dataframe is 18-times-repeated gene name, and the rest three columns are the gene's information. Each dataframe describes different gene.

Now I'd like to iterate the list of dataframe (i.e, a list of gene and their respective information) over the boxplot, to get plots on each gene; however, I am not sure how to deal with the ggtitle below:

Here is my simplified boxplot function:

```
box <- function(df){
  df %>%
    ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,4], y = df[,2])) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
    ggtitle(g)
}
```

g is the gene name in each dataframe in the df_list

and when I run `lapply(df_list,box)`,
I got `Error: Mapping should be created with` aes()`or`aes_()`.`

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you used `dplyr` pipe, the first argument of `ggplot()` is already filled, leading `df` to be understood as `aes` argument.

```
box <- function(df){
  df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = df[,4], y = df[,2])) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
    ggtitle(g)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `df[,4]` or `df[,2]` use column names in `aes`. Assuming the column names on x-axis is `col1` and that on y-axis is `col2` try  -

```
box <- function(df, g){
  df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
    ggtitle(df$g[1])
}

lapply(df_list,box)
```

`g` is the column name in the dataframe, so we can take the first value from it in title.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it with another example dataset (Species instead of genes):

```r
library(tidyverse)
plots <-
  iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  mutate(
    plt = data %>% map2(Species, ~ {
      .x %>%
        ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
          geom_boxplot() +
          labs(title = .y)
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(plt)
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = c(name, value)`?
plots[[1]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>